# how do I import an array containing dictionary from a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file with cookies inside. It looks like this:

```
[{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"},
 {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"},
 {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"},
 {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}]
```

I store it into a string variable like this:

```
with open ('example.txt', "r") as myfile:
    cookie = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

I am not able to transform it into an array with each elements as dictionary.
I have tried `cookie2 = cookie.split(',')` and `cookie2 = cookie.split('},{')` but you get the obvious issue: it breaks dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like `json` data, you can use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to parse it. Something like -

```
import json
with open('<filename>') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Demo -

file -

```
[{"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"},{"key1":"value", 
"key2":"value", "key3":"value"},{"key1":"value", "key2":"value", 
"key3":"value"},{"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":"value"}]
```

Code -

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('a.txt','r') as f:
...     pprint.pprint(json.load(f))
...
[{'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value'},
 {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value'},
 {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value'},
 {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your input seems formatted as JSON, look into the `json` module. It will do the parsing for you: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html

```
import json
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!